# Ruby FANN gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fann

I am trying to use the FANN(Fast Artificial Neural Network) library within a rails project. Therefore, I have installed fan (the installation seems to be ok, I've followed some guides online). Also, I've added the `ruby-fann` gem to my Gemfile and it has been installed. However, when I run `rspec` in order to test my code I get a very long error which has the following beginning:

```
/app/models/neural_network.rb:12: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000009
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0044 p:---- s:0175 e:000174 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0043 p:---- s:0173 e:000172 CFUNC  :new
c:0040 p:---- s:0156 e:000155 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0039 p:0021 s:0152 e:000151 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177
c:0038 p:0006 s:0149 e:000148 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385
c:0037 p:0006 s:0147 e:000146 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343
c:0036 p:0006 s:0145 e:000144 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474
c:0035 p:0006 s:0143 e:000142 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614 [FINISH]
c:0034 p:---- s:0141 e:000140 CFUNC  :call
c:0033 p:0022 s:0138 e:000137 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247
c:0032 p:0014 s:0133 e:000132 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-rails-3.2.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:113 [FINISH]
c:0031 p:---- s:0130 e:000129 CFUNC  :instance_exec
c:0030 p:0015 s:0126 e:000125 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333
c:0029 p:0013 s:0121 e:000120 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:387
c:0028 p:0013 s:0116 e:000115 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616 [FINISH]
c:0027 p:---- s:0114 e:000113 CFUNC  :call
c:0026 p:0022 s:0111 e:000110 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247
c:0025 p:0060 s:0106 E:0019c8 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:617
c:0024 p:0115 s:0100 E:0011f8 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474
c:0023 p:0014 s:0094 E:0020f8 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343
c:0022 p:0026 s:0090 E:001468 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385
c:0021 p:0132 s:0086 E:000b68 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:174
c:0020 p:0054 s:0080 e:000079 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:549 [FINISH]
c:0019 p:---- s:0075 e:000074 CFUNC  :map
c:0018 p:0014 s:0072 e:000071 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:545
c:0017 p:0102 s:0068 e:000067 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:512
c:0016 p:0011 s:0060 e:000059 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0057 e:000056 CFUNC  :map
c:0014 p:0009 s:0054 e:000053 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110
c:0013 p:0046 s:0052 e:000051 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526
c:0012 p:0009 s:0048 e:000047 BLOCK  /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109
c:0011 p:0017 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62
c:0010 p:0018 s:0041 e:000040 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108
c:0009 p:0022 s:0037 E:000590 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86
c:0008 p:0088 s:0032 E:0012c0 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70
c:0007 p:0024 s:0025 E:000e58 METHOD /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38
c:0006 p:0023 s:0021 E:0003a0 TOP    /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0019 e:000018 CFUNC  :load
c:0004 p:0135 s:0015 E:002610 EVAL   /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0011 e:000010 CFUNC  :eval
c:0002 p:0118 s:0005 E:0024b8 EVAL   /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:002370 TOP    [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62:in `report'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109:in `block in run_specs'
/Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526:in `with_suite_hooks'
```

And the following ending:

```
 1849 /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb
 1850 /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/statsample-1.4.3/lib/statsample/test.rb
 1851 /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/statsample-1.4.3/lib/statsample/bivariate/pearson.rb
 1852 /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/statsample-1.4.3/lib/statsample/bivariate.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

The code on line `/app/models/neural_network.rb:12` is

```
train = RubyFann::TrainData.new(inputs: inputs, desired_outputs: desired_outputs)
```

Comment: Do you run the `bundle install`?

Comment: yes I did run the command & the gem was installed

Comment: `/app/models/neural_network.rb:12:`, can you show the code?

Comment: I've added it above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. One of the arguments I was passing to RubyFann::TrainData.new did not have the required type.